# check whether every word of string2 exists in string1 in R

Tags: r

I want to check whether every word of string2 exists in string1. example

```
string1 <- "My name is John Smith"
string2 <- "My Smith"
```

I expect following code should return TRUE

```
str_detect(string1, string2)
```

but it is returning false

Answer (score 2):

If everything is `TRUE` then it's present otherwise no.

```
> string1 <- "My name is John Smith"
> string2 <- "My Smith"
> 
> strsplit(string2,' ')[[1]] %in% strsplit(string1,' ')[[1]]
[1] TRUE TRUE
>
```

Test case:

```
> string3 <- 'He is Smith'
> strsplit(string3,' ')[[1]] %in% strsplit(string1,' ')[[1]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.  It is `TRUE` if all elements of the split `string2` are found in `string1`.

```
all(sapply(unlist(strsplit(string2, " ")), grepl, string1))

[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_detect` from `stringr`:

```
string1 <- "My name is John Smith"
string2 <- "My Smith"

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

string1 %>%
  str_detect(str_split(string2, " ", simplify = TRUE)) %>%
  all()
# [1] TRUE
```

Instead of `unlist()`ing, you can use `simplify = TRUE` from `str_split`